# Where do I put Oracle EntityFramework Mapping settings for LinqPad?

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, mapping, linqpad

I have an EntityFramework model which has a boolean field. To make the mapping to the oracle database work properly, our application has the following additions in the app.config.

`<oracle.dataaccess.client>`

`<settings>`

`<add name="bool" value="edmmapping number(1,0)" />`

`</settings>`

`</oracle.dataaccess.client>`

Unfortunately when using Linqpad, I get the all to familiar mapping error:
error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type 'Edm.Boolean[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=]' of member 'someBoolean' in type 'Model.SomeItem' is not compatible with 'OracleEFProvider.number[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=,Precision=1,Scale=0]'

I tried putting the settings in the LINQPad.exe.config, put they are ignored. I also tried the original assembly as well as the Oracle.DataAccess.dll.

The model is in a custom assembly (.dll) and I selected the new Oracle.DataAccess Provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting them into LINQPad.config instead of LINQPad.exe.config. The former is for your queries; the latter is for LINQPad itself.